# SQLite with Entity Framework 6: relative path?

Tags: visual-studio, entity-framework, sqlite

I'm trying to use SQLite with Entity Framework 6 in my WPF application. When I create Entity Data Model in the project, I connect to *.db file using absolute path, because relative path doesn't work for some reason. So my connection looks something like

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="Model1ConnectionString" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SQLite.EF6;provider connection string='data source=&quot;C:\Users\gtmaster\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\SQLiteTest\SQLiteTest\test.db&quot;'" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

If some other developer clones reporsitory with this connection he gets `unable to open database file` error, because absolute path to `test.db` in the project is obviously different on his machine. 
How can I write relative path in app.config so entity models could work without changing it everytime?

Answer (score 0):

using relative path for the DB file

the source of the db file is in App.config

```
<add name="ProjectDBEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/ProjectDBModel.csdl|res://*/ProjectDBModel.ssdl|res://*/ProjectDBModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SQLite.EF6;provider connection string='data source=&quot;c:\Users\Heckl\Documents\Dropbox\Else\visual studio\SqLiteTry\ProjectDB.db&quot;'" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
```

the data source must be absoulte

you can use the |DataDirectory| substitution string in App.config

```
<add name="ProjectDBEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/ProjectDBModel.csdl|res://*/ProjectDBModel.ssdl|res://*/ProjectDBModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SQLite.EF6;provider connection string='data source=&quot;|DataDirectory|ProjectDB.db&quot;'" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
```

the substitution string has to be set

```
string executable = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;            
string path = (System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(executable));
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", path);  
// ...
var db = new ProjectDBEntities()
```

problems:

exception at the first LINQ command

the change in App.config is not always detected by VS, you might have to rebuild solution manually

the code above set the location of the exe file in the solution\project\bin\debug folder

the db file is in the solution folder

check the value of db.Database.Connection.ConnectionString in a watch window during debug

you can copy the db file into the debug folder also

Answer (score 0):

`|DataDirectory|` is good for production environment, but when you do `update-database` migrations apply to newly created database in EF packet directory, because EF cant get your project generated connection string and use self `DataDirectory` value.